# In R , there are `actual` and `budget` values,how to add new variable and calculate the variable values

Tags: r, tidyverse

In variable `type` ,there are `actual` and `budget` values,how to add new  variable and calculate the variable value ? Current code can work, but a little bording. Anyone can help? Thanks!

```
 ori_data <- data.frame(
    category=c("A","A","A","B","B","B"),
    year=c(2021,2022,2022,2021,2022,2022),
    type=c("actual","actual","budget","actual","actual","budget"),
    sales=c(100,120,130,70,80,90),
    profit=c(3.7,5.52,5.33,2.73,3.92,3.69)
    )
```

Add sales inc%

```
ori_data$sales_inc_or_budget_acheved[category=='A'&year=='2022'&type=='actual'] <- 
  ori_data$sales[category=='A'&year=='2022'&type=='actual']/
  ori_data$sales[category=='A'&year=='2021'&type=='actual']-1
```

Add budget acheved%

```
ori_data$sales_inc_or_budget_acheved[category=='A'&year=='2022'&type=='budget'] <- 
  ori_data$sales[category=='A'&year=='2022'&type=='actual']/
  ori_data$sales[category=='A'&year=='2022'&type=='budget']
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `group_by` and an `if_else`you could do:

```r
library(dplyr)

ori_data |> 
  group_by(category) |> 
  arrange(category, type, year) |> 
  mutate(sales_inc_or_budget_achieved = if_else(type == "actual", 
                                                sales / lag(sales) - 1, 
                                                lag(sales) / sales)) |> 
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 6 × 6
#>   category  year type   sales profit sales_inc_or_budget_achieved
#>   <chr>    <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>                        <dbl>
#> 1 A         2021 actual   100   3.7                        NA    
#> 2 A         2022 actual   120   5.52                        0.2  
#> 3 A         2022 budget   130   5.33                        0.923
#> 4 B         2021 actual    70   2.73                       NA    
#> 5 B         2022 actual    80   3.92                        0.143
#> 6 B         2022 budget    90   3.69                        0.889
```

And using `across` you could do the same for both `sales` and `profit`:

```
ori_data |> 
  group_by(category) |> 
  arrange(category, type, year) |> 
  mutate(across(c(sales, profit), ~ if_else(type == "actual", 
                                            .x / lag(.x) - 1, 
                                            lag(.x) / .x), 
                .names = "{.col}_inc_or_budget_achieved")) |> 
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 6 × 7
#>   category  year type   sales profit sales_inc_or_budget_achie… profit_inc_or_b…
#>   <chr>    <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>                      <dbl>            <dbl>
#> 1 A         2021 actual   100   3.7                      NA               NA    
#> 2 A         2022 actual   120   5.52                      0.2              0.492
#> 3 A         2022 budget   130   5.33                      0.923            1.04 
#> 4 B         2021 actual    70   2.73                     NA               NA    
#> 5 B         2022 actual    80   3.92                      0.143            0.436
#> 6 B         2022 budget    90   3.69                      0.889            1.06
```

Comment: Thanks , another question: 【|>】 equals 【%>%】 ?

Comment: For the example: Yes. (: |> is the native pipe (introduced with R > 4.1) and could in most cases replaced by the `magrittr` pipe %>%. In more general case there are however some differences.

Answer (score 1):

Answer from stefan suits perfectly well, however, I would suggest you rearrange your data first.
In my opinion sales and profit are types of measures (aka observations) and actual and budget are the measurements here:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

ori_data2 <- 
  ori_data %>% 
  pivot_longer(c(sales, profit)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = type, values_from = value) %>% 
  group_by(category, name) %>% 
  arrange(year, .by_group = TRUE)
```

then your calculations become much more easier:

```
ori_data2 %>% 
  mutate(increase = actual / lag(actual) - 1,   # compare to the year before
         budget_acheved = actual / budget) %>%   # compare actual vs. budget
  filter(year == 2022)  # you can filter for year of interest
  mutate(across(c(increase, budget_acheved), scales::percent))  # and format as percent
```